# How to use moviepy generated videos in Vegas?

Tags: python, codec, moviepy

For some reason I can't use generated videos by Moviepy in Vegas but before editing them with Moviepy I'm able to import into Vegas.

I just can use these videos if I convert each one using Handbrake (mp4 to mp4).

Could this problem be caused by incorrect codecs or something like that?

**How to import videos made in Moviepy to Vegas without having to convert them in another program?**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: done.ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: add "audio_codec="aac"
Now I can import it to Vegas